# How can I disable the SIM PIN?

Tags: security

My phone currently requires a SIM-PIN *in addition* to the pin to unlock the phone, which feels a bit redundant. How can I remove the SIM-level PIN?

I have looked through all the areas of `settings` and can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can disable SIM security at the bottom of "phone settings", accessible from the menu of the phone application/dialer. You will need to enter the SIM PIN in order to disable it.

"lock + wallpaper" only provides access to the *phone* PIN.

[image: settings -> applications -> phone -> swipe down -> SIM settings -> SIM security on/off-switch]
<sup>A screenshot from a Windows Phone 8.1 dual SIM device</sup>

Comment: This answer is outdated, the procedure is different since Windows Phone 8.1 GDR2 (8.10.15148.160), see my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

On my Lumia 830, running Windows Phone 8.1 GDR2 (8.10.15148.160) the answer above is not valid anymore.

Instead, I succeeded in removing the SIM PIN security at phone boot by following [this](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/calling-and-messaging/use-a-pin-to-lock-my-sim-card) procedure; I just swiped on the button *SIM security* to turn it **off**.

```
On Start Start icon, tap Phone Phone tile > More icon > Settings.

Turn off SIM security Toggle switch
```

Please note, the phone will ask you the SIM PIN one last time.

Comment: I'm not sure what model I have (that's hard to find out too) but your answer was very useful to me. I would never have looked there! Under Settings I have "mobile+SIM" and below that "SIM settings" and that's NOT where you can activate/deactivate SIM lock - makes no sense